# Wordpress Fatal error

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm new to wordpress, I got this error when trying to update style.css in wordpress theme, i don't think css cause the crash please help me what cause this problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'td_mobile_theme' not found in
>   /home/staging/www/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/mobile/includes/td_global_mob.php:20
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/staging/www/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/mobile/functions.php(8):
>   require_once() #1 /home/staging/www/wp-settings.php(424):
>   include('/home/staging/w...') #2 /home/staging/www/wp-config.php(92):
>   require_once('/home/staging/w...') #3
>   /home/staging/www/wp-load.php(37): require_once('/home/staging/w...') #4 /home/staging/www/wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('/home/staging/w...') #5 /home/staging/www/index.php(17):
>   require('/home/staging/w...') #6 {main} thrown in
>   /home/staging/www/wp-content/themes/Newspaper/mobile/includes/td_global_mob.php
>   on line 20

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're either missing a plugin or it has been deactivated.

From looking at the error message and searching for unique terms, I guess you have the Newspaper-Theme installed. [Their website](https://forum.tagdiv.com/install-via-ftp/) mentions "tagDiv Mobile theme" as an optional plugin. Maybe your theme has been modified so that it's no longer optional but required?
See if that plugin is installed and activated.